# Data Structures in C (Single Linked List) - Follow-up

Tags: c, linked-list

This is a follow-up from my [previous question!](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/107497/data-structures-in-c-single-linked-list)

I cleaned up the code and added all the notes from the answers.

I have also updated the code on [github](https://github.com/AntonioCS/acsclib/tree/master/DataStructures/LinkedList/Single)

> LinkedList.h

```
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H
#define LINKEDLIST_H

#ifdef  __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

    typedef struct LinkedListNode LinkedListNode;

    typedef struct LinkedList {
        LinkedListNode *head;
        LinkedListNode *tail;
    } LinkedList;

    struct LinkedListNode {
        void *data;
        LinkedListNode *next;
    };

    LinkedList *LLInit();

    LinkedListNode *LLAddHead(LinkedList *, void *);
    LinkedListNode *LLAddTail(LinkedList *, void *);
    LinkedListNode *LLAdd(LinkedList *, void *);

    void *LLRemoveHead(LinkedList *);
    void *LLRemoveTail(LinkedList *);
    void *LLRemoveNode(LinkedList *, LinkedListNode *);

    LinkedListNode *LLFindNodeByData(LinkedList *, void *, int (*LLFindCompareFuncPtr)(const void *, const void *));
    LinkedListNode *LLFindNodeByNext(LinkedList *, LinkedListNode *);


#ifdef  __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif  /* LINKEDLIST_H */
```

> LinkedList.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "LinkedList.h"
#include "../../../dbg.h"

typedef int (*LLFindCompareFuncPtr)(const void *, const void *);

enum LLAddStrategy {
    HEAD,
    TAIL
};

struct LLFindNodeBaseParams {
    LinkedList *ll;

    void *data;
    LLFindCompareFuncPtr compareFunc;

    LinkedListNode *node;
    LinkedListNode *next;
};

struct FindResult {
    LinkedListNode *prev;
    LinkedListNode *node;
};

typedef bool(*findByFuncPtr)(struct LLFindNodeBaseParams *, struct FindResult *, LinkedListNode *);

//<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Private functions">


static bool FindResultSetResult(bool condition, struct FindResult *res, LinkedListNode *node) {
    if (condition) {
        res->node = node;
    } else {
        res->prev = node;
    }

    return condition;
}

static bool FindByData(struct LLFindNodeBaseParams *params, struct FindResult *res, LinkedListNode *node) {
    return FindResultSetResult(params->compareFunc(params->data, node->data) == 0, res, node);
}

static bool FindByNode(struct LLFindNodeBaseParams *params, struct FindResult *res, LinkedListNode *node) {
    return FindResultSetResult(params->node == node, res, node);
}

static bool FindByNextNode(struct LLFindNodeBaseParams *params, struct FindResult *res, LinkedListNode *node) {
    return FindResultSetResult(params->next == node->next, res, node);
}

struct FindResult *InitFindResult() {
    struct FindResult *res = malloc(sizeof (struct FindResult));
    check(res, "Unable to allocate memory for FindResult");

    res->node = NULL;
    res->prev = NULL;

    return res;

error:
    return NULL;
}

static struct FindResult *FindNodeBase(struct LLFindNodeBaseParams *params) {
    findByFuncPtr fptr = NULL;

    if (params->data != NULL && params->compareFunc != NULL) {
        fptr = FindByData;
    } else if (params->node != NULL) {
        fptr = FindByNode;
    } else if (params->next != NULL) {
        fptr = FindByNextNode;
    }

    check(fptr, "Bad params for FindNodeBase, can't determine find function");

    LinkedListNode *node = params->ll->head;
    struct FindResult *res = InitFindResult();

    check(res, "Unable to allocate memory for FindResult structure");
    bool foundNode = false;

    while (node != NULL) {
        if ((foundNode = fptr(params, res, node))) {
            break;
        }
        node = node->next;
    }

    if (foundNode == false) {
        res->node = NULL;
        res->prev = NULL;
    }

    return res;

error:
    return NULL;
}

static struct FindResult *LLFindNode(LinkedList *ll, LinkedListNode *node) {

    struct LLFindNodeBaseParams fnbParams = {
        .ll = ll,
        .node = node
    };
    struct FindResult *res = FindNodeBase(&fnbParams);
    return res;
}


/**
 *
 * @param data
 * @param next
 * @return
 */
static LinkedListNode *NodeInit(void *data, LinkedListNode *next) {
    LinkedListNode *lln = malloc(sizeof (LinkedListNode));
    check(lln, "Unable to allocate memory for linked list node");

    lln->data = data;
    lln->next = next;

    return lln;
error:
    return NULL;
}

/**
 * Add an item to the linked list in the head or the tail
 *
 * @param ll
 * @param data
 * @param type
 * @return LinkedListNode *
 */
static LinkedListNode *LLAddBase(LinkedList *ll, void *data, enum LLAddStrategy stype) {
    check(ll, "LLAddBase received null pointer");
    LinkedListNode *node = NodeInit(data, NULL);

    if (ll->head == NULL) {
        ll->tail = ll->head = node;
    } else {
        if (stype == HEAD) {
            node->next = ll->head;
            ll->head = node;
        } else {
            ll->tail->next = node;
            ll->tail = ll->tail->next;
        }
    }

    return node;
error:
    return NULL;
}

//</editor-fold>

/**
 * Initialize a linked list
 * 
 * @return LinkedList *
 */
LinkedList *LLInit() {
    LinkedList *ll = malloc(sizeof (LinkedList));
    check(ll, "Unable to allocate memory for linked list");

    ll->head = NULL;
    ll->tail = NULL;

    return ll;

error:
    return NULL;
}

//<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Add Functions">

/**
 * Add a node to the start of the Linked List
 * 
 * @param ll
 * @param data
 * @return LinkedListNode *
 */
LinkedListNode *LLAddHead(LinkedList *ll, void *data) {
    return LLAddBase(ll, data, HEAD);
}

/**
 * Add a node to the end of the Linked List
 *
 * @param ll
 * @param data
 * @return LinkedListNode *
 */
LinkedListNode *LLAddTail(LinkedList *ll, void *data) {
    return LLAddBase(ll, data, TAIL);
}

/**
 * Shorter alias for LLAddTail
 * 
 * @param ll
 * @param data
 * @return LinkedListNode *
 */
LinkedListNode *LLAdd(LinkedList *ll, void *data) {
    return LLAddTail(ll, data);
}

//</editor-fold>

//<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Remove functions">

/**
 * @param ll Pointer to linkedlist
 * @return void * to the data in the node
 */
void *LLRemoveHead(LinkedList *ll) {
    return LLRemoveNode(ll, ll->head);
}

/**
 * @param ll Pointer to linkedlist
 * @return void * to the data in the node
 */
void *LLRemoveTail(LinkedList *ll) {
    return LLRemoveNode(ll, ll->tail);
}

/**
 *
 * @param ll Pointer to linkedlist
 * @param node Pointer to node to delete
 * @return void * to the data in the node
 */
void *LLRemoveNode(LinkedList *ll, LinkedListNode *node) {
    void *data = node->data;
    struct FindResult *res = LLFindNode(ll, node);

    check(res->node, "Node not found on List");

    if (node == ll->head) {
        ll->head = ll->head->next;

        if (ll->head == NULL) {
            ll->tail = NULL;
        }
    } else {
        res->prev->next = node->next;

        if (node == ll->tail) {
            ll->tail = res->prev;
        }
    }

    free(node);
    return data;

error:
    return NULL;
}
//</editor-fold>

//<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Find functions">

/** 
 * @param ll
 * @param data
 * @param func
 * @return
 */
LinkedListNode *LLFindNodeByData(LinkedList *ll, void *data, int (*func)(const void *, const void *)) {

    struct LLFindNodeBaseParams fnbParams = {
        .ll = ll,
        .data = data,
        .compareFunc = func
    };
    struct FindResult *res = FindNodeBase(&fnbParams);

    LinkedListNode *node = res->node;
    free(res);

    return node;
}

/**
 * @param ll
 * @param nodeNext
 * @return
 */
LinkedListNode *LLFindNodeByNext(LinkedList *ll, LinkedListNode *nodeNext) {

    struct LLFindNodeBaseParams fnbParams = {
        .ll = ll,
        .next = nodeNext
    };
    struct FindResult *res = FindNodeBase(&fnbParams);

    LinkedListNode *node = res->node;
    free(res);

    return node;
}

//</editor-fold>
```

Comment: Why didn't you combine `typedef struct LinkedListNode LinkedListNode; struct LinkedListNode {
        void *data;
        LinkedListNode *next;
    };` to `typedef struct LinkedListNode {
        void *data;
        struct LinkedListNode *next;
    } LinkedListNode;`, just like you did the other one?

Comment: It was just that I could use the type inside the struct for the *next. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Memory Leak

In `LLRemoveNode()`, you call `LLFindNode()`, which returns a allocated `FindResult` structure.  However, you never free that `FindResult` struct, so it gets leaked.

My advice is that instead of `LLFindNodeBase()` returning an allocated `FindResult` structure, you have it take a `FindResult` structure pointer from the caller that gets filled in instead.  That way, you don't have to allocate anything on the heap and remember to free it later on.  In other words, something like this:

```
static void FindNodeBase(const struct LLFindNodeBaseParams *params,
                         struct FindResult *result);
```

You could have it return an `int` or `bool` if you wanted to make errors returned that way.  Also note the `const` keyword on the `params` argument because that argument is never modified within the function.

Comment: Thanks for this! I have added a free to the function and will add the const.