# Data structures in C (doubly linked list)

Tags: c, linked-list

Continuing from my last [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/107651/data-structures-in-c-single-linked-list-follow-up) I have now implemented a Double Linked list. All the code (with tests) is also available on [GitHub](https://github.com/AntonioCS/acsclib/tree/master/DataStructures/LinkedList/Double).

**DobLinkedList.h**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#ifndef DobLINKEDLIST_H
#define DobLINKEDLIST_H

#ifdef  __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

    typedef struct DobLinkedListNode {
        void *data;

        struct DobLinkedListNode *prev;
        struct DobLinkedListNode *next;
    } DobLinkedListNode;

    typedef struct DobLinkedList {
        DobLinkedListNode *head;
        DobLinkedListNode *tail;

        unsigned int nodeCount;
    } DobLinkedList;

    DobLinkedList *DobLLInit();

    DobLinkedListNode *DobLLAddHead(DobLinkedList *, void *);
    DobLinkedListNode *DobLLAddTail(DobLinkedList *, void *);
    DobLinkedListNode *DobLLAdd(DobLinkedList *, void *);

    void *DobLLRemoveHead(DobLinkedList *);
    void *DobLLRemoveTail(DobLinkedList *);
    void *DobLLRemoveNode(DobLinkedList *, DobLinkedListNode *);

    DobLinkedListNode *DobLLFindNodeByData(DobLinkedList *, void *, bool (*comp)(const void *, const void *));
    DobLinkedListNode *DobLLFindNodeByNext(DobLinkedList *, DobLinkedListNode *);
    DobLinkedListNode *DobLLFindNodeByPrev(DobLinkedList *, DobLinkedListNode *);

#ifdef  __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif  /* DobLINKEDLIST_H */
```

**DobLinkedList.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "DobLinkedList.h"
#include "../../../dbg.h"

/**
 * Initialize a linked list
 *
 * @return LinkedList *
 */
DobLinkedList *DobLLInit() {
    DobLinkedList *dobll = malloc(sizeof (DobLinkedList));
    check(dobll, "Unable to allocate memory for Double Linked List");

    dobll->head = NULL;
    dobll->tail = NULL;
    dobll->nodeCount = 0;

    return dobll;

error:
    return NULL;
}

//<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Add Functions">

enum AddStrategy {
    HEAD,
    TAIL
};

static DobLinkedListNode *NodeInit(void *data, DobLinkedListNode *prev, DobLinkedListNode *next) {
    DobLinkedListNode *doblln = malloc(sizeof (DobLinkedListNode));
    check(doblln, "Unable to allocate memory for linked list node");

    doblln->data = data;
    doblln->prev = prev;
    doblln->next = next;

    return doblln;
error:
    return NULL;
}

static DobLinkedListNode *DobLLAddBase(DobLinkedList *dobll, void *data, enum AddStrategy stype) {
    check(dobll, "LLAddBase received null pointer");
    DobLinkedListNode *node = NodeInit(data, NULL, NULL);

    if (dobll->head == NULL) {
        dobll->tail = dobll->head = node;
    } else {
        if (stype == HEAD) {
            node->next = dobll->head;
            dobll->head->prev = node;
            dobll->head = node;
        } else {
            dobll->tail->next = node;
            node->prev = dobll->tail;
            dobll->tail = node;
        }
    }

    dobll->nodeCount++;
    return node;
error:
    return NULL;
}

DobLinkedListNode *DobLLAddHead(DobLinkedList *dobll, void *data) {
    return DobLLAddBase(dobll, data, HEAD);
}

DobLinkedListNode *DobLLAddTail(DobLinkedList *dobll, void *data) {
    return DobLLAddBase(dobll, data, TAIL);
}

DobLinkedListNode *DobLLAdd(DobLinkedList *dobll, void *data) {
    return DobLLAddTail(dobll, data);
}

//</editor-fold>

//<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Remove functions">

void *DobLLRemoveHead(DobLinkedList *dobll) {
    return DobLLRemoveNode(dobll, dobll->head);
}

void *DobLLRemoveTail(DobLinkedList *dobll) {
    return DobLLRemoveNode(dobll, dobll->tail);
}

void *DobLLRemoveNode(DobLinkedList *dobll, DobLinkedListNode *node) {
    void *data = node->data;

    if (node == dobll->head) {
        dobll->tail = dobll->head = dobll->head->next;

        if (dobll->head) {
            dobll->head->prev = NULL;
        }
    } else {
        node->prev->next = node->next;

        if (node == dobll->tail) {
            dobll->tail = node->prev;
        }
        else {
            node->next->prev = node->prev;
        }
    }

    dobll->nodeCount--;
    free(node);
    return data;
}

//</editor-fold>

//<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Find functions">

DobLinkedListNode *DobLLFindNodeByData(DobLinkedList *dobll, void *data, bool(*comp)(const void *, const void *)) {
    DobLinkedListNode *current = dobll->head;

    while (current != NULL) {
        if (comp(data, current->data) == true) {
            break;
        }

        current = current->next;
    }

    return current;
}

//</editor-fold>
```

Comment: Consider using pointers to pointers when deleting nodes.

Comment: @xrthdsf Hey, could you please give more details on the approach you are suggesting? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

## Bug

In your node removal code, you have this:

> ```
> if (node == dobll->head) {
>     dobll->tail = dobll->head = dobll->head->next;
> ```

You should only be setting `tail` if `tail` and `head` are the same node.

## Possible NULL dereference

Your `DobLLRemoveHead()` and`DobLLRemoveTail()` functions currently don't check if there are actually any nodes to remove.  If the list is empty, calling those functions will result in a NULL dereference and crash.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell what `check()` is supposed to do (assuming it's part of dbg.h) nor can I tell if they have anything to do with the `error:` labels.  Labels are usually used along with `goto`s, but there aren't any in the code.  If code execution never reaches them, then you may have to use a conditional to determine whether or not the functions should return `NULL`.